# What's the difference between tests and specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, automated-tests

I decided to try out [MiniTest](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/) and noticed pretty quickly that it supported something called "specs". I had seen these [referenced before](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures) but thought it was just an alternate test syntax associated with factories, but if that were the case then why would MiniTest need to support them both?

We only covered tests when I was taught Ruby on Rails, so I don't really know anything about specs. When I Google specs I find a lot of stuff about how to write good ones but nothing explaining what they *are*. What's the difference between tests and specs?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Google for tests vs. Specs. Some good reads pop up:

- https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/specs-vs-tests
- http://betterspecs.org/

My opinion is, that specs read more 'natural' and feel more like true specifications of the functionality of the code when compared to mini-test et.al.

Rspec is a good example of a DSL, specifically written to write tests that make sense when read, even for people less technically inclined.

But in the end, use whatever makes you feel more comfortable. A test written is almost always better then no test written, because you feel uncomfortable using the testing framework

**edit**

After rereading your question, you seem to specifically ask about mini-test specs. It is an addition to minitests which adds rspec-like syntax to minitest. Everything above still applies.

Comment: Now googling gives your answer as the first result, hehe

Answer (score 99):

A spec, short for specification, comes from behavior driven testing, and encourages the mindset where you are defining 'what' the software does.

Calling it a test leads to a much more general way of thinking about the code, and does not reinforce the idea that you should be testing the interface (instead of the implementation) as well.

That said, regardless of how you write them, or what you call them, the point is to have an automated way of verifying the correctness of your code, so that you can proceed with confidence.

Comment: +1 for "a spec, short for specification", contractions always keep me guessing

Answer (score 4):

In practice, there is 1 difference I see too often in projects.

Developers joining a project using `*.spec.[ts/js]` ask where are the "test files". It would be much clearer if test files are called test files.

When writing tests, I say "I wrote a test", not "I wrote a specification". "Writing tests". Unit testing, system testing, integration testing, smoke testing... Not smoke specification , "system specification" (confusing?), "integration specification". This is also confusing when you work on projects with actual specifications, e.g. [ably specification](https://github.com/ably/specification).

Comment: nope, based on @SciPhi, i agreed `A spec (*.spec.[ts/js]), short for specification, comes from behavior driven testing, and encourages the mindset where you are defining 'what' the software does` while on the other hand test (*.test.[ts/js]) are based on TDD mindset. so they will have their own way for defining any kind of "test" based on which driven development build mindset we wanna used or workspaces you used..

Comment: having a different `spec` directory, instead of using the existing `test` directory, was IMHO a mistake, and an unnecessary one, at least in Ruby where you filter the files on `_spec` or `_test` anyway.  

This is especially true of Minitest, where your can use both Spec and Test and it doesn't care.

FWIW, I use the `test` directory to align with other languages we use, although I use MiniTest Spec DSL and `_spec` filenames.