# Whatever I try to create a test with Playwright I get this error: No tests found. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, playwright

[image: first test]

I try to create a test with Playwright, but the result is always Error: No tests found
Even though I followed all the steps to create it properly it resulted in an Error message in the terminal as you can see in the screenshot... I can't even guess what can be the problem, I am completely new to this...

```
{
  "name": "playwright-course",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "playwright course",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.39.0"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "name": "playwright-course",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "playwright-course",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@playwright/test": "^1.39.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@playwright/test": {
      "version": "1.39.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@playwright/test/-/test-1.39.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-3u1iFqgzl7zr004bGPYiN/5EZpRUSFddQBra8Rqll5N0/vfpqlP9I9EXqAoGacuAbX6c9Ulg/Cjqglp5VkK6UQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "playwright": "1.39.0"
      },
      "bin": {
        "playwright": "cli.js"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/fsevents": {
      "version": "2.3.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-2.3.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-xiqMQR4xAeHTuB9uWm+fFRcIOgKBMiOBP+eXiyT7jsgVCq1bkVygt00oASowB7EdtpOHaaPgKt812P9ab+DDKA==",
      "dev": true,
      "hasInstallScript": true,
      "optional": true,
      "os": ["darwin"],
      "engines": {
        "node": "^8.16.0 || ^10.6.0 || >=11.0.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/playwright": {
      "version": "1.39.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/playwright/-/playwright-1.39.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-naE5QT11uC/Oiq0BwZ50gDmy8c8WLPRTEWuSSFVG2egBka/1qMoSqYQcROMT9zLwJ86oPofcTH2jBY/5wWOgIw==",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "playwright-core": "1.39.0"
      },
      "bin": {
        "playwright": "cli.js"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16"
      },
      "optionalDependencies": {
        "fsevents": "2.3.2"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/playwright-core": {
      "version": "1.39.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/playwright-core/-/playwright-core-1.39.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-+k4pdZgs1qiM+OUkSjx96YiKsXsmb59evFoqv8SKO067qBA+Z2s/dCzJij/ZhdQcs2zlTAgRKfeiiLm8PQ2qvw==",
      "dev": true,
      "bin": {
        "playwright-core": "cli.js"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May you put the test code into the question as a text-based [mcve]?

Comment: Please may you share your `package.json` and `playwright.config.ts`? --- Also, do you not get an error asking you to change `require` to `import`? I do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [playwright 'no tests found.' on simple copy of example.spec.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71053528/playwright-no-tests-found-on-simple-copy-of-example-spec-ts) --- If this isn't the duplicate, it's probably because you used `npm i -D playwright` and not `npm i -D @playwright/test`

Comment: {
  "name": "playwright-course",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "playwright Course",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.39.0"
  }
}

Comment: Nope, I don't get that error about change require to import...

Comment: I've tried with both... npm i -D playwright and  npm i -D @playwright/test

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected that "darwin" but nothing has changed...

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71053528/playwright-no-tests-found-on-simple-copy-of-example-spec-ts again

Comment: Pls share your config file code.

Comment: Wait fellas, seems like I don't have this important thing here playwright.config.ts... I don't have it... It was not in the tutorial... So, I just need to create a new file with that name and copy the code that I've found here?

Comment: @MarijaČolaković make sure to follow [their tutorial](https://playwright.dev/docs/intro#installing-playwright)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works perfectly, something was wrong with the first tutorial...