# What is the difference between spec.js and test.js?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

What are the distinctions between executing `sum.test.js` and `sum.spec.js` files in Jest? Despite yielding identical output when executed, are both files essentially performing equivalent tasks within the testing framework? [sum.spec.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI18r.png) [sum.test.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPb27.png).

What is the difference between them? Are they doing the same thing?

Comment: Execution is the same. it is philosophical question what name reads better. Using one over another is a team preference. Here is an old discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802030/whats-the-difference-between-tests-and-specs